# CORS issue while authenticating an external web app to Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I'm trying to authenticate to saleforce using Connected App and web application, My request succeed with Postman but when I try send the request from the Web App I get CORS issue and OAuth unsupported_grant_type error

I did all the configs for the connected App and added localhost to CORS whitelist in my Salesforce Org and even hosted the web app in heroku, but still get the same ERROR !
here are the screenshots

[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4DQV.png) 
[screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9TuG.png)

i'm still stucked whith this for 2 wekks, please Help.
Thank you :)

Comment: have you tried mode: 'no-cors' in fetch ?

Comment: @BabarKhan yes I already tried with mode :'no-cors' , the request succeed but i got no data in the response ! I need to get the access_token !